# Collectstatic is giving NoSuchKey while using s3boto3 and manifestfilemixin

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, browser-cache

```
class NSStaticStorage(ManifestFilesMixin, S3Boto3Storage):
    pass
NoSuchKey: An error occurred (NoSuchKey) when calling the ListObjects operation: The specified key does not exist.
```

I am getting this error while integrating s3boto and manifest for cache busting

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem using s3boto with ManifestFilesMixin when I tried to run `./manage.py collectstatic --clear`. I had to add `--clear` parameter to remove file duplicates created by manifest file versioning. So I assume that you've used `--clear` parameter too.

There is a [bug](https://github.com/jschneier/django-storages/issues/436) in [django-storages](https://github.com/jschneier/django-storages) related to `--clear`.

By now I simply removed `--clear` and use `./manage.py collectstatic` as soon as the issue with file duplicates is not critical for me.

People in the [github issue](https://github.com/jschneier/django-storages/issues/436) suggest to clear files from s3 manually.